# Vector:: erase segmentation fault

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, erase

I got a segmentation fault in this code and I cannot get why:

```
vector <double> *point;
for (int i = 0; i < point->size(); i += 3) {
    for (int j = i + 3; j < point->size(); j += 3) {
        if (distance((*point)[i], (*point)[i + 1],(*point)[i + 2], (*point)[j],(*point)[j + 1], (*point)[j + 2]) < treshold){
             point->erase(point->begin() + j, point->begin() + j * 3);
             j -= 3;
        }
    }
}
```

point is a vector of coordinates of points, something like (x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z3,...,xn,yn,zn). 
Distance it's a function that calculate the euclidean distance between 2 points given the 6 coordinate.
Basically what I would do is something like "if two points are too close to each other delete one of them".
But I get segmentation fault.
Any idea?

Comment: No, `point` is not a vector, it’s a *pointer to* vector. What does it point to?

Comment: Where exactly in this code does the segmentation fault occur?

Comment: why is each series of 3 `doubles` considered one point?  Why don't you have a `vector` of `coordinate`s where each `coordinate` holds 3 doublts?

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad.
The pointer to vector it's initialized, this is just an extract of my code. In fact if I make the cout of the size before this loop, it works.
And the reason why I use a vector of double instead of one of coordinate it's because the library I'm using requires a vector of double.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `erase` line is wrong. You have `j * 3` when you probably mean `j + 3`.

Answer (score 4):

```
vector <double> *point;
```

declares an uninitialized pointer which you attempt to access with `point->size()`.

Thus, undefined behavior & a crash.

I'd go with a simple object instead

```
vector <double> point;
```

or, *if you must* use dynamic memory:

```
vector <double> *point = new vector<double>;
```

Comment: I'd assume that it's actually initialized or he probably would have noticed, and that Brangdon's answer is the real problem.

Comment: @MooingDuck I admit I didn't look that far :)